# snapshot.val() returning null in build deploy in Vercel & Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js, vercel

I am making a blog application in Next.js, Firebase Realtime Database & Vercel for hosting. When i run it on my local machine, everything works perfectly, i get back all data from Firebase, even when i run `npm run build`  on my local machine, everything goes on like clockwork, but when in production i deploy it to netlify, the `snapshot.val()` function in Firebase Realtime Database, always returns a `null` value, however when i log  the snapshot object, i get a proper console.log with the `DataSnapshot` & its values.

I am making a blog application in Next.js, Firebase & Vercel for hosting. When i run it on my local machine, everything works perfectly, i get back all data from Firebase, even when i run `npm run build`  on my local machine, everything goes on like clockwork, but when in production i deploy it to netlify, the `snapshot.val()` function in firebase, always returns a `null` value, however when i log  the snapshot object, i get a proper console.log as follows on both the dev & prod console:

```
DataSnapshot {
  _node: ChildrenNode {
    children_: SortedMap {
      comparator_: [Function: NAME_COMPARATOR],
      root_: LLRBEmptyNode {}
    },
    priorityNode_: null,
    indexMap_: IndexMap { indexes_: [Object], indexSet_: [Object] },
    lazyHash_: null
  },
  ref: ReferenceImpl {
    _repo: Repo {
      repoInfo_: [RepoInfo],
      forceRestClient_: false,
      authTokenProvider_: [FirebaseAuthTokenProvider],
      appCheckProvider_: [AppCheckTokenProvider],
      dataUpdateCount: 0,
      statsListener_: null,
      eventQueue_: [EventQueue],
      nextWriteId_: 1,
      interceptServerDataCallback_: null,
      onDisconnect_: [Object],
      transactionQueueTree_: [Tree],
      persistentConnection_: [PersistentConnection],
      key: 'https://blog-2ba4f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/',
      stats_: [StatsCollection],
      server_: [PersistentConnection],
      statsReporter_: [StatsReporter],
      infoData_: [SnapshotHolder],
      infoSyncTree_: [SyncTree],
      serverSyncTree_: [SyncTree]
    },
    _path: Path { pieces_: [Array], pieceNum_: 0 },
    _queryParams: QueryParams {
      limitSet_: false,
      startSet_: false,
      startNameSet_: false,
      startAfterSet_: false,
      endSet_: false,
      endNameSet_: false,
      endBeforeSet_: false,
      limit_: 0,
      viewFrom_: '',
      indexStartValue_: null,
      indexStartName_: '',
      indexEndValue_: null,
      indexEndName_: '',
      index_: PriorityIndex {}
    },
    _orderByCalled: false
  },
  _index: PriorityIndex {}
}
```

This `null` returned value is not going away, no matter what i try and whichever solutions I found online, and honestly, without proper db return values,the whole app is useless.

Here are some basic facts:

- That snapshot is loaded correctly and is being logged as console.log(snapshot) in the environment.
- The snapshot does contain data, as proven in the proper execution and logging, on my local machine.
- There isn't an issue with the code logic. The code logic is correct and that there are no bugs or errors in the code that could be causing the issue.
- It isn't a permission issue. The read permission rule is already set to `true` in the Firebase Realtime Database.

Any help is appreciated, i have been stuck on this for 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase returns a snapshot object as a query result even when there is no data.
Try to check whether the result is empty by logging `console.log(snapshot.exists())`.

Probably there is some difference between Dev and Prod environment. Check manually Prod database by exporting it to a JSON file.